# Efficient looping and comparing properties of two similar objects

Tags: python

I have a function `find()` that needs to loop through a lot of objects to identify a similar object by comparing a bunch of properties.

```
class Target:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

class Source:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


def find(target: Target, source_set: set):
    for s in source_set:
        if s.a == target.a:
            if s.b == target.b:
                if s.c == target.c:
                    print("Found!")


source_set = {
    Source(a=1, b=2, c=3),
    Source(a=4, b=2, c=4)
}

target = Target(a=4, b=2, c=4)

find(target, source_set)
```

The current function is very slow as my `source_set` can be millions.

The source_set creation and its `Source` objects can be adjusted (e.g. the type). The source_set itself is not modified after initialisation.

The `Source` objects creation's input is coming from a dict with the same properties. One `Source`'s raw input data is like this:

```
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

The source_set is searched with many targets.

Is there a nice way to be more efficient? I'm hoping to not need to change the data structure.

Comment: You could design an indexing mechanism in your classes that allows finding equivalent values quickly. But there's nothing built-in that does this.

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify the classes? Or accept an answer with external libraries? Do you compare only instance variables?

Comment: yes; yes; and yes; @Corralien

Comment: Do you care about finding only the first source that matches the target or all of them?

Comment: good point, all of them as it would be a problem if there were more than 1 @AlexG

Comment: Do you have any control over the creation of the source_set or any further information about it? For example if it is sorted, then you could do binary search. Or if you will use the source_set multiple times (for example checking multiple targets). If not, I think you will not be able to get faster than linear time (comparing elements one by one).

Comment: @AlexG added more details on the source_set in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Without any external libraries, you can modify the `__hash__` method of each class

```
class Target:

    ...
       
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(frozenset(self.__dict__.items()))


class Source:

    ...

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(frozenset(self.__dict__.items()))
```

Now try:

```
count = len({hash(target),}.intersection(map(hash, source_set)))
print(count)

# Output
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Pandas`:

```
# Python env: pip install pandas
# Miniconda env: conda install pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([s.__dict__ for s in source_set])
sr = pd.Series(target.__dict__)
print(df)
print(sr)

# Output of source_set
   a  b  c
0  4  2  4
1  1  2  3

# Output of target
a    4
b    2
c    4
dtype: int64
```

Find same rows:

```
>>> sr.eq(df).all(axis=1).sum()
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `source_set` is only created once, but searched with many targets (as stated in your question), it is beneficial to invest time into creating a data structure for the `source_set` (which is only done once) if the reward is a time gain for the comparison later on (which is done multiple times). 
Python's `set` provides the desired functionality. Internally it is somehow implemented as a hash map (not sure on this). To make use of the `in` statement, the elements **in** the `set` and also the elements that are **compared to** the `set` have to be hashable and comparable, i.e. both provide a `__hash__` method and one of them provide a `__eq__` method.

```
class Target:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b, self.c))

class Source:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b and self.c == other.c

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b, self.c))
```

Now building the `set` of `Source` elements is a time investment, because for each element that is added, the `__hash__` method is applied.

```
source_set = {
    Source(a=1, b=2, c=3),
    Source(a=4, b=2, c=4),
}
```

However, the reward is that now checking if a `target` is in the `source_set` happens in constant time compared to your current approach by comparing the `target` consecutively to each of the `Source`s which is in linear time.

```
target = Target(a=4, b=2, c=4)
target in source_set
# returns True
```